# Eclipse の画面で SVN リポジトリの追加ボタンが表示されない

Tags: eclipse, svn

Eclipseのsvnで＋マークの追加ボタンが急になくなってしまいました。

SVNリポジトリー・エクスプローラーを開いていますが、写真の＋マークがなくなってしまい
どうしたら出てくるのか全然さがせなく、どうしたら出てくるのか教えて頂きたいです。

**該当のボタン (表示されている例):**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**現在の状態 (+ボタンが無い):**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ＋マークが無くなった状態の画面キャプチャーも載せて下さい。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。もう一つのPCがインターネットが使えず、携帯からの写真になってしまいます。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

外していたらすみません。

写真を見る限りだと、SVNリポジトリー・エクスプローラのパースペクティブではすべてのビューが閉じられた状態に見えます。画像の方で示されているSVNリポジトリービューが閉じられた状態なだけのようです。

「ウィンドウ」メニューから「ビューの表示」で「SVNリポジトリー」を選択すると表示されるようになりませんか？

Comment: 出ました！！ありがとうございます！